# How to prevent Bash's while loop from trimming whitespace?

Tags: bash

I need to pipe data into a while loop in a bash script, but it keeps trimming the whitespace. For example:

```
echo "   test" | while read i; do echo "$i"; done
```

How can I prevent it from doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
echo "   test" | while IFS= read i; do echo "$i"; done
```